# Modal form submitting multiple times

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap modal is submitting multiple times, it appears to be for the amount of times the modal has been opened.

**Code**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Close Modal when done.
function CloseModal() {
    $("#SkillModalWindow").modal("hide");
}
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "SkillGroup", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    OnSuccess = "CloseModal"
},
new { id = "CreateSkillGroups" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.Hidden("JobRoleId", (int)ViewBag.JobRoleID)

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Add New Skills to Job Role</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="CreateModal">@Html.Partial("_Create")</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Move the script include tags to the page that calls the modal. Seems as though it keeps each modal in memory until the page that calls the modal is reloaded.

Answer (score 2):

You are just hiding the modal, not resetting it. You need to reset the data after you post.

```
$('#SkillModalWindow').data('modal', null);
```